# Glassfish, Java EE: This bundle has no bean of name[]

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have a Java EE application witch is an AER with a EJB and a WAR.

Running the EJB on Glassfish I got the following error:

I have the configurtion file: glassfish-ejb-jar.xml:

```
    <!DOCTYPE glassfish-ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//
    DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 EJB 3.1//EN" 
   "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-ejb-jar_3_1-1.dtd">
   <glassfish-ejb-jar>
  <display-name>First Module</display-name>
 <enterprise-beans>
<ejb>
    <ejb-name>ejbentities</ejb-name>
    <jndi-name>ejbEntities</jndi-name>
    <bean-pool>
        <steady-pool-size>10</steady-pool-size>
        <resize-quantity>10</resize-quantity>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
        <pool-idle-timeout-in-seconds>600</pool-idle-timeout-     in-seconds>
    </bean-pool>
    <bean-cache>
        <max-cache-size>100</max-cache-size>
        <resize-quantity>10</resize-quantity>
        <removal-timeout-in-seconds>3600</removal-timeout-in-seconds>
        <victim-selection-policy>LRU</victim-selection-policy>
    </bean-cache>
</ejb>
<cmp-resource>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/__default</jndi-name>
    <create-tables-at-deploy>true</create-tables-at-deploy>
    <drop-tables-at-undeploy>true</drop-tables-at-undeploy>
</cmp-resource>
</enterprise-beans>
<keep-state>true</keep-state>
</glassfish-ejb-jar>
```

I have the Glassfish Server error:

```
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [ejbEntities] :      Referencing error: This bundle has no bean of name [ejbentities]
Info:   Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port  0.0.0.0:8080
Info:   Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
 Info:   visiting unvisited references
    Info:   visiting unvisited references
    Warning:   AS-DEPLOYMENT-00015
    Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [ejbEntities]
    Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Referencing error: This    bundle has no bean of name [ejbentities]
at   org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.descriptor.EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.getEjbByNa       me(EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.java:323)
at   org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.descriptor.EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.getEjbByName(EjbBundleDescriptorImpl.java:307)
at org.glassfish.ejb.deployment.node.runtime.EjbNode.setElementValue(EjbNode.java:133)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.SaxParserHandler.endElement(SaxParserHandler.java:617)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLNSDTDValidator.endNamespaceScope(XMLNSDTDValidator.java:266)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:2005)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:879)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2973)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:318)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.DOLUtils.readRuntimeDeploymentDescriptor(DOLUtils.java:512)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRuntimeDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:719)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRuntimeDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:695)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:184)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:203)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

  Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [ejbEntities] :    Referencing error: This bundle has no bean of name [ejbentities]
```

What name do I have to give to the bean?
I also called it Person because I have a Person bean. The result was the same.
When I remove the line:

```
     <ejb-name>Person</ejb-name>
```

I get a:

```
Exception while deploying the app [ejbEntities]
```

error

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really have an EJB with the name ejbentities? You would have more help if you also provided code of your EJB class here.